# cant figure out how to add shortcut icon

Tags: html

i have tried making shortcut icons with a tutorial but it dosent work most of the time.
ill show what i tried doing

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="image/favicon.png">`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="image/favicon.ico">`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.png">`

they all dont work but its probably i have another link element for css but i dont know

Comment: What exactly do you expect "shortcut icon" to do…?

Answer (score 0):

Favicons are created with a `link` element in the within the head class.

The link element's `rel` property contains space-separated properties, similar to `class` in other elements. `shortcut` and `icon` are used to denote a favicon, however `icon` can also be used alone.

If your icon is an ICO file, use `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">`. If your icon is a PNG, change the type to `"image/png"`.

Make sure it has the correct file extension on your server and the icon is being hosted properly. You can open up the `Network` tab in developer tools to check if the request for the favicon is going through. `404` means it has failed, and if that is the case it should be red. If it works but you still don't see it, it's probably a bug with the browser.

Comment: i have a folder for the website files and i simply run the website off of the chrome file:/// extension and thats all and it dosent work

Comment: Don't do that. Use a proper web server. If you have to use file:///, remove the / from the href and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

check the paths twice. use absolute path like "/image/favicon.png" as much as you can. if you are using relative, consider the page you are in. when you are in the root directory, relative path like "image/smth.png" is considered as "www.mysite.com/image/smth.png".
but if you are in a sub directory, relative path is considered differently, like
"www.mysite.com/sub/sub2/image/smth.png"
this is relative: 
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.png">` 
this is absolute: 
 `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/image/favicon.png">`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with url to your favicon instead of absolute/relative path as the example given below (add your favicon link(s) after the meta tags):

```html
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <title>Testing Favicons</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Adding favicons</h3>
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="100" alt="favicon" >
</body>
</html>
```